# viewDidAppear height is 656 in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting a height of 656 in my viewDidAppear on a view controller. This is not the correct height that I am expecting from an iPhone 5. Any idea why this might be happening? I have a UIView that I added as a subview of this UIViewController and I set the struts such that it will always stick to the bottom of the UIViewController. However because the height is 656, I can no longer see this UIView. ANy idea why?

Here's my code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated
{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.size.height); 
}
```

This is how I am initializing the VC:

```
  SavedViewController *savedStoriesVC = [[SavedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SavedViewController" bundle:nil];
    savedStoriesVC.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    savedStoriesVC.delegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:savedStoriesVC];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the code you are using to get the height.

Comment: CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; Use this for getting height

Comment: Check your view in interface builder.... You might have set it to a larger size there....

Comment: Using that same code I get the proper values for the screen and view (568 and 548, respectively).

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if that's the height of a yet-to-be-announced device.

Comment: whats the height of the subview you are adding to this UIView?

Comment: added more code and screenshots.. the subview height is 68

Comment: Maybe the parent height is incorrect, or the main window size.... Check everything!

Comment: well at least doing   CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; gives me the correct height

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem.  I was able to "fix" it by turning off all of the struts and springs.  But then, of course, rotations didn't work.